# About the second derivative of a symmetric function

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, submanifold, symmetric-functions

Let $\Sigma$ be a hypesurface immersed in a Riemannian manifold $M.$ Suppose that $h$ is the second fundamental form of $\Sigma.$

Now, let $\sigma_p$ denote the $p$-th elementary symmetric polynomial in the eigenvalue of $h.$ What does the notation $\frac{\partial\sigma_p}{\partial h_{ij}}$ mean?

In the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.3988v2, this notation provides a symmetric $2$-tensor. However,  it is not clear to me. For example, what is $\frac{\partial\sigma_1}{\partial h_{ij}}$?

Comment: Well, $\sigma_p$ is a function of all the entries of $h$. For example, $\sigma_1 = \text{tr}(h) = h_{11} + \dots + h_{nn}$ and $\sigma_n = \det(h)$. There are formulas for all of them.

Comment: Thank for your response. Now, it is clear to me!